# How to ajust "responsive mode" zoom in Firefox web dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is there a way to adjust responsive mode zoom in Firefox Web Dev Tools? Every time I use responsive mode for large screens, Firefox displays it in the original size (pic 1). I can still zoom out  using ctrl + mouse wheel, but then the screen is not centered (pic 2). Is there a way to get it to work similar to Chrome Dev Tools (pic 3)?

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to work similar to Chrome with these 2 steps:

1. Zoom can be change in responsive mode by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse scrolling.
2. There are settings on the left top side of screen and you need to choose "Left align viewport":

[image: screen]

Answer (score -1):

You can get it to work similar to Chrome with these 2 steps:

Zoom can be change in responsive mode by Ctrl++ / Ctrl+- or with Ctrl + mouse scrolling.

There are settings on the left top side of screen and you need to choose "Left align viewport":